# How to blend surfaces with multiple alpha values?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

Is there a way to get surfaces with multiple alpha values to blend correctly? I have to use SDL_SetSurfaceAlphaMod to modify how the texture blends, and that overwrites the whole surface's alpha channel! I've made a small demo program to show what I mean.

What I want is [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OolIV.png), what I'm getting is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9bOq.png).

The code

```
#include <SDL.h>

void putPixel(SDL_Surface *surface, int x, int y, Uint32 pixel){

  Uint32 *pixels = (Uint32*)surface->pixels;
  pixels[(y * surface->w) + x] = pixel;
}

// After some experimenting I found that this would get the alpha onto the surface correctly
void FillAlpha(SDL_Surface* Surface){
  Uint32 Pixel;
  Uint8 RGBA[4] = {0, 0, 0, 100};
  Pixel = RGBA[3]<<24 | RGBA[2]<<16 | RGBA[1]<<8 | RGBA[0];
  for(int x=0; x<32; x++){
    for(int y=0; y<32; y++){
      putPixel(Surface, x, y, Pixel);
    }
  }
  RGBA[3] = 150;
  Pixel = RGBA[3]<<24 | RGBA[2]<<16 | RGBA[1]<<8 | RGBA[0];
  for(int x=32; x<64; x++){
    for(int y=0; y<32; y++){
      putPixel(Surface, x, y, Pixel);
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
  SDL_Window* Window = NULL;
  SDL_Surface* Screen = NULL;
  SDL_Surface* Alpha = NULL;

  SDL_Event Event;

  bool Quit = false;

  Window = SDL_CreateWindow("Alpha test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 128, 128, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
  if(Window == NULL) return 1;
  Screen = SDL_GetWindowSurface(Window);
  if(Screen == NULL) return 2;

  Alpha = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(NULL, 64, 32, 32,
                               Screen->format->Rmask, Screen->format->Gmask,
                               Screen->format->Bmask, Screen->format->Amask);
  if(Alpha == NULL) return 3;
  SDL_SetSurfaceBlendMode(Alpha, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
  FillAlpha(Alpha);

  while(!Quit){
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&Event)){
      if(Event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN){
        if(Event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE){
          Quit = true;
        }
      }else if(Event.type == SDL_QUIT){
        Quit = true;
      }
    }
    SDL_FillRect(Screen, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(Screen->format, 255, 255, 255));
    SDL_BlitSurface(Alpha, NULL, Screen, NULL);
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(Window);
  }

  SDL_Quit();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are just not initializing your surface properly. On my machine for example, `Screen->format->?mask` produced values that were no correct for the case. So, instead of

```
Alpha = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(NULL, 64, 32, 32,
    Screen->format->Rmask, Screen->format->Gmask,
    Screen->format->Bmask, Screen->format->Amask);
```

try this (I assume you are on little-endian cpu):

```
unsigned int rmask = 0x000000ff;
unsigned int gmask = 0x0000ff00;
unsigned int bmask = 0x00ff0000;
unsigned int amask = 0xff000000;

Alpha = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(NULL, 64, 32, 32, rmask, gmask, bmask, amask);
```

for further reference, [see official wiki](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRGBSurface).